# Does Visual Studio 2015 help when refactoring VB.NET namespaces?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

VS 2015 has some great refactoring capabilities: I can rename a class and VS automatically modifies all occurrences of that class name in the project.

Now, as part of a larger rewrite, I'd like to move a few classes into their own namespace, e.g.

```
Public Class MyClass
    ....
End Class
```

becomes

```
Namespace SomeFeature
    Public Class MyClass
        ....
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Will VS 2015 help me or do I need to fix all usages of `MyClass` manually?

Comment: @CloseVoter This isn't off topic.

Comment: It would be somewhat likely that you'll have to add a Imports directive at the top of the source code file that uses MyClass.  Sure, the lightbulb helps you add that quickly.